# How can I set an uncommon screen resolution on GNU/Linux with an Arc 380 GPU and X11?

Tags: linux, driver, intel, x11, screen-resolution

I have a monitor with an uncommon resolution (1920x860). When I connect it to the iGPU (Intel Iris Pro II) its native resolution is detected egregiously; however, if I connect it to the GPU (Intel Arc 380) the only resolution provided is 1280x720. I can only connect it via HDMI.

On Wayland the resolution of this trouble is quite impossible at the moment: the edid file of said monitor is wrong (and I have neither the skills nor the ability to write about it; I cannot risk damaging the hardware).

On X11 something is doable thanks to xrandr, but always limited. I can indeed enable 1920x1080, which comes a little close to the native resolution of my screen, but the form factor is wrong (and the screen looks smeared).

To come to this conclusion I had to make many attempts, but unfortunately after a month I am still with a GPU that cannot set the resolution of my monitor correctly.

I am on Artix Linux Kernel 6.8.2-artix1-1, plasmashell 6.0.2, X11. I am using the i915 driver, properly loaded. Here are some other infos, hope someone could be of some help.

```
$ lspci | grep VGA
03:00.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation DG2 [Arc A380] (rev 05)
```

```
$ glxinfo | grep "OpenGL version"
OpenGL version string: 4.6 (Compatibility Profile) Mesa 24.0.3-arch1.2
```

```
$ xrandr
Screen 0: minimum 320 x 200, current 1920 x 1080, maximum 16384 x 16384
HDMI-3 connected primary 1920x1080+0+0 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 278mm x 124mm
   1280x720      60.00    59.94  
   1920x1080R    59.93* <-- note: manually added (working)
   1920x860R     59.89  <-- note: manually added (not working)
DP-3 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
HDMI-4 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
VGA-1-1 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
DP-1-1 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
HDMI-1-1 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
DP-1-2 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
HDMI-1-2 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)

the wrong edid via $ get-edid | parse-edid:
Section "Monitor"
        Identifier "L1"
        ModelName "L1"
        VendorName "MSR"
        # Monitor Manufactured week 23 of 2021
        # EDID version 1.3
        # Digital Display
        DisplaySize 270 120
        Gamma 2.20
        Option "DPMS" "true"
        Horizsync 30-81
        VertRefresh 56-76
        # Maximum pixel clock is 170MHz
        #Not giving standard mode: 1280x720, 60Hz

        #Extension block found. Parsing...
        Modeline        "Mode 2" +hsync +vsync interlace
        Modeline        "Mode 0" +hsync +vsync 
        Modeline        "Mode 1" 74.250 1280 1390 1420 1650 720 725 730 750 +hsync +vsync
        Option "PreferredMode" "Mode 2"
EndSection
```

```
$ grep EE /var/log/Xorg.0.log
[     4.530] Current Operating System: Linux red 6.8.2-artix1-1 #1 SMP PREEMPT_DYNAMIC Wed, 27 Mar 2024 20:16:29 +0000 x86_64
        (WW) warning, (EE) error, (NI) not implemented, (??) unknown.
[     4.554] (EE) Failed to load module "intel" (module does not exist, 0)
[     4.558] (EE) Failed to load /usr/lib/xorg/modules/drivers/fbdev_drv.so: /usr/lib/xorg/modules/drivers/fbdev_drv.so: undefined symbol: fbdevHWSave
[     4.558] (EE) Failed to load module "fbdev" (loader failed, 0)
[     5.165] (II) Initializing extension MIT-SCREEN-SAVER
[    14.433] (II) XINPUT: Adding extended input device "BJYP-L1 Device BJYP-L1-V1.09" (type: TOUCHSCREEN, id 16)
[    50.663] (II) XINPUT: Adding extended input device "BJYP-L1 Device BJYP-L1-V1.09" (type: TOUCHSCREEN, id 16)
[   480.527] (EE) modeset(0): failed to set mode: No such file or directory
[   492.496] (II) XINPUT: Adding extended input device "BJYP-L1 Device BJYP-L1-V1.09" (type: TOUCHSCREEN, id 16)
```

```
$ grep WW /var/log/Xorg.0.log
        (WW) warning, (EE) error, (NI) not implemented, (??) unknown.
[     4.535] (WW) The directory "/usr/share/fonts/misc" does not exist.
[     4.537] (WW) The directory "/usr/share/fonts/Type1" does not exist.
[     4.537] (WW) The directory "/usr/share/fonts/100dpi" does not exist.
[     4.537] (WW) The directory "/usr/share/fonts/75dpi" does not exist.
[     4.554] (WW) Warning, couldn't open module intel
```

and dmesg | grep i915:

```
    2.324978] i915 0000:00:02.0: [drm] Found 128MB of eDRAM
[    2.325745] i915 0000:00:02.0: ROM [??? 0x00000000 flags 0x20000000]: can't assign; bogus alignment
[    2.325749] i915 0000:00:02.0: [drm] Failed to find VBIOS tables (VBT)
[    2.326197] WARNING: CPU: 1 PID: 451 at drivers/gpu/drm/i915/display/intel_ddi.c:4793 intel_ddi_init+0x1b5/0x1050 [i915]
[    2.326396] Modules linked in: usbhid(+) crct10dif_pclmul apple_mfi_fastcharge crc32_pclmul polyval_clmulni polyval_generic i915(+) gf128mul ghash_clmulni_intel snd_hda_codec_realtek snd_hda_codec_generic sha512_ssse3 sha256_ssse3 eeepc_wmi sha1_ssse3 aesni_intel asus_wmi snd_hda_intel snd_intel_dspcfg ledtrig_audio platform_profile snd_intel_sdw_acpi i8042 crypto_simd snd_hda_codec sparse_keymap cryptd drm_buddy i2c_algo_bit serio iTCO_wdt rapl ppdev at24 snd_hda_core rfkill intel_pmc_bxt ttm intel_cstate mei_hdcp mxm_wmi iTCO_vendor_support mei_pxp wmi_bmof intel_uncore snd_hwdep drm_display_helper snd_pcm i2c_i801 i2c_dev cec snd_timer crypto_user intel_gtt lpc_ich i2c_smbus pcspkr e1000e snd mei_me ptp soundcore parport_pc video mei pps_core parport mac_hid wmi acpi_pad ext4 crc32c_generic crc16 mbcache jbd2 crc32c_intel xhci_pci xhci_pci_renesas
[    2.326449] RIP: 0010:intel_ddi_init+0x1b5/0x1050 [i915]
[    2.326625]  ? intel_ddi_init+0x1b5/0x1050 [i915 ba15940b0812ba6411d4d08f04798e49b3370e47]
[    2.326784]  ? intel_ddi_init+0x1b5/0x1050 [i915 ba15940b0812ba6411d4d08f04798e49b3370e47]
[    2.326956]  ? __pfx_intel_ddi_init+0x10/0x10 [i915 ba15940b0812ba6411d4d08f04798e49b3370e47]
[    2.327110]  ? intel_ddi_init+0x1b5/0x1050 [i915 ba15940b0812ba6411d4d08f04798e49b3370e47]
[    2.327267]  ? intel_ddi_init+0x1b5/0x1050 [i915 ba15940b0812ba6411d4d08f04798e49b3370e47]
[    2.327433]  ? __pfx_intel_ddi_init+0x10/0x10 [i915 ba15940b0812ba6411d4d08f04798e49b3370e47]
[    2.327588]  intel_bios_for_each_encoder+0x38/0x50 [i915 ba15940b0812ba6411d4d08f04798e49b3370e47]
[    2.327753]  intel_setup_outputs+0x386/0x8b0 [i915 ba15940b0812ba6411d4d08f04798e49b3370e47]
[    2.327933]  intel_display_driver_probe_nogem+0x14c/0x210 [i915 ba15940b0812ba6411d4d08f04798e49b3370e47]
[    2.328096]  i915_driver_probe+0x656/0xba0 [i915 ba15940b0812ba6411d4d08f04798e49b3370e47]
[    2.328263]  i915_init+0x25/0xc0 [i915 ba15940b0812ba6411d4d08f04798e49b3370e47]
[    2.328391]  ? __pfx_i915_init+0x10/0x10 [i915 ba15940b0812ba6411d4d08f04798e49b3370e47]
[    2.330341] [drm] Initialized i915 1.6.0 20230929 for 0000:00:02.0 on minor 1
[    2.330639] i915 display info: display version: 8
[    2.330641] i915 display info: cursor_needs_physical: no
[    2.330642] i915 display info: has_cdclk_crawl: no
[    2.330643] i915 display info: has_cdclk_squash: no
[    2.330644] i915 display info: has_ddi: yes
[    2.330644] i915 display info: has_dp_mst: yes
[    2.330645] i915 display info: has_dsb: no
[    2.330646] i915 display info: has_fpga_dbg: yes
[    2.330646] i915 display info: has_gmch: no
[    2.330647] i915 display info: has_hotplug: yes
[    2.330648] i915 display info: has_hti: no
[    2.330648] i915 display info: has_ipc: no
[    2.330649] i915 display info: has_overlay: no
[    2.330650] i915 display info: has_psr: yes
[    2.330650] i915 display info: has_psr_hw_tracking: yes
[    2.330651] i915 display info: overlay_needs_physical: no
[    2.330652] i915 display info: supports_tv: no
[    2.330652] i915 display info: has_hdcp: no
[    2.330653] i915 display info: has_dmc: no
[    2.330653] i915 display info: has_dsc: no
[    2.343211] i915 0000:00:02.0: [drm] Cannot find any crtc or sizes
[    2.343264] snd_hda_intel 0000:00:03.0: bound 0000:00:02.0 (ops i915_audio_component_bind_ops [i915])
[    2.346501] i915 0000:00:02.0: [drm] Cannot find any crtc or sizes
[    2.350364] i915 0000:00:02.0: [drm] Cannot find any crtc or sizes
[    2.370415] i915 0000:03:00.0: vgaarb: deactivate vga console
[    2.370753] i915 0000:03:00.0: [drm] Can't resize LMEM BAR - platform support is missing
[    2.370766] i915 0000:03:00.0: [drm] Local memory IO size: 0x0000000010000000
[    2.370768] i915 0000:03:00.0: [drm] Local memory available: 0x000000017c800000
[    2.370769] i915 0000:03:00.0: [drm] Using a reduced BAR size of 256MiB. Consider enabling 'Resizable BAR' or similar, if available in the BIOS.
[    2.392428] i915 0000:03:00.0: [drm] Finished loading DMC firmware i915/dg2_dmc_ver2_08.bin (v2.8)
[    2.402470] i915 0000:03:00.0: [drm] GT0: GuC firmware i915/dg2_guc_70.bin version 70.20.0
[    2.402474] i915 0000:03:00.0: [drm] GT0: HuC firmware i915/dg2_huc_gsc.bin version 7.10.3
[    2.413667] i915 0000:03:00.0: [drm] GT0: GUC: submission enabled
[    2.413670] i915 0000:03:00.0: [drm] GT0: GUC: SLPC enabled
[    2.413910] i915 0000:03:00.0: [drm] GT0: GUC: RC enabled
[    2.473066] [drm] Initialized i915 1.6.0 20230929 for 0000:03:00.0 on minor 2
[    2.474053] i915 display info: display version: 13
[    2.474055] i915 display info: cursor_needs_physical: no
[    2.474056] i915 display info: has_cdclk_crawl: no
[    2.474057] i915 display info: has_cdclk_squash: yes
[    2.474058] i915 display info: has_ddi: yes
[    2.474059] i915 display info: has_dp_mst: yes
[    2.474059] i915 display info: has_dsb: yes
[    2.474060] i915 display info: has_fpga_dbg: yes
[    2.474061] i915 display info: has_gmch: no
[    2.474061] i915 display info: has_hotplug: yes
[    2.474062] i915 display info: has_hti: no
[    2.474063] i915 display info: has_ipc: yes
[    2.474063] i915 display info: has_overlay: no
[    2.474064] i915 display info: has_psr: yes
[    2.474064] i915 display info: has_psr_hw_tracking: no
[    2.474065] i915 display info: overlay_needs_physical: no
[    2.474066] i915 display info: supports_tv: no
[    2.474066] i915 display info: has_hdcp: yes
[    2.474067] i915 display info: has_dmc: yes
[    2.474068] i915 display info: has_dsc: yes
[    2.499911] snd_hda_intel 0000:04:00.0: bound 0000:03:00.0 (ops i915_audio_component_bind_ops [i915])
[    2.501894] fbcon: i915drmfb (fb0) is primary device
[    2.575285] i915 0000:03:00.0: [drm] fb0: i915drmfb frame buffer device
[    3.135620] mei i915.mei-gscfi.768-46e0c1fb-a546-414f-9170-b7f46d57b4ad: Could not read FW version ret = -19
[    3.135623] mei i915.mei-gscfi.768-46e0c1fb-a546-414f-9170-b7f46d57b4ad: FW version command failed -5
[    3.541576] i915 0000:03:00.0: [drm] GT0: HuC: authenticated for all workloads
[    3.541583] mei_pxp i915.mei-gsc.768-fbf6fcf1-96cf-4e2e-a6a6-1bab8cbe36b1: bound 0000:03:00.0 (ops i915_pxp_tee_component_ops [i915])
```

Thank you for your time and patience.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! [so] is for programming questions, not questions about using or configuring Unix and its utilities. [unix.se] or [su] would be better places for questions like this.

Comment: Thank you for the welcome, your time and answer. :) I will try as you suggest.